# Understanding code used to draw quads in OpenGL 3.3+ core using triangles

Tags: c++, c, opengl, opengl-3

I'm trying to draw a quad for a background (2D) using OpenGL 3.x+.  Quads are deprecated, so the goal is to use two triangles to make a rectangle that fills the screen.  It's working, but I'm not 100% clear on everything here.

1. Setup

   ```
   GLuint positionBufferObject;
   GLfloat vertexPositions[] =
   {
       -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
       -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
       -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
   };
   glGenBuffers(1, &positionBufferObject);
   glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBufferObject);
   glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexPositions), vertexPositions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
   ```

   - I understand the `vertexPositions`, it's an array of vertices.
   - `glGenBuffers()` is saying, I want 1 buffer and assign id to `&positionBufferObject`?
   - `glBufferData()` uploads the `vertexPositions` to the GPU's memory; but how does it know were to upload it since I didn't give it an ID?
2. Draw

   ```
   glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
   glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
   glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 5);
   glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
   ```

   - `glEnableVertexAttribArray()` just says I'm going to be drawing with array 0?
   - `glDrawArrays()` - what if I want to draw two vertex arrays?  How does it know which ones to render?  It knows that from the above command?
   - Not sure what `glVertexAttribPointer()` does?
   - `glDrawArrays()` is clear.
3. Clean up, I think this is right?

   ```
   glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
   glDeleteBuffers(1, &positionBufferObject);
   ```

   I only do the setup/cleanup once.

Bonus points:

- Is this the most effective way to render this?  I read that I'm suppose to be submitting and be rendering in "batches" [?] since 3.x+ doesn't do immediate mode any more.   There is also only one array, so batches won't help performance in this case, but if I had say "a very large number" of vertxArrays to draw, would it be the same process?
- In setup they are storing the array id as positionBufferObject, but have it hardcoded in the rendering loop. Seems like it would get confusing after a dozen or so arrays, why isn't it good practice to use the variable instead of hardcode it?

Comment: Instead of a quad you could use a triangle fan, which, in the case of only 4 vertices sent will behave almost exactly like a quad. You can glPrimitiveRestartIndex to put multiple triangle fans into single glDrawElements call.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`glGenBuffers(1, &positionBufferObject);` says "make a vertex buffer object, and `positionBufferObject` is its ID."

`glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBufferObject);` says "`positionBufferObject` is now the current `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`."

`glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexPositions), vertexPositions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);` says "upload `vertexPositions` to the ID currently bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` (which is `positionBufferObject`)."

`glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);` says "vertex attribute array 0 is now available for use."

`glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);` says "vertex attribute array 0 is to be interpreted as consisting of groups of 4 floats."

`glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 5);` says "draw a triangle strip with five indices from every enabled array."

`glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);` says "we're done for the time being with vertex attribute array 0."

Comment: Thanks.  1) How could you deal with more than one GL_ARRAY_BUFFER? 2) glVertexAttribPointer is basically saying "how" to use the Array and the format of it?

Comment: 1) I'm not an expert enough yet to answer this question :) 2) Yes; for example, your `glVertexAttribPointer` call would be different if your positions and colors were interleaved as opposed to being in different continuous blocks. 3) Call it on every display update.

Comment: @user697111 For 1) glDrawArrays will use whichever VBO is currently bound, so if you want to draw from a second VBO just call glBindBuffer with the second VBO's ID and call glDrawArrays again.

Comment: @Incresulous Monk No, look at Nicolas' answer for clarification!

Answer (score 4):

In answer to user697111's question about multiple arrays, it's quite simple.

Each vertex attribute needs to be associated with a buffer object. Rather than specifying the buffer object with glVertexAttribPointer, the association is done through GL_ARRAY_BUFFER. When you call glVertexAttribPointer (or any gl*Pointer call), the buffer that is **currently** bound to GL_ARRAY_BUFFER will be used as the source for that attribute. So, consider the following:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, myPositionData);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, ..., 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, myColorData);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, ..., 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glDrawArrays(...);
```

Attribute 0 will come from the buffer object `myPositionData`, and attribute 1 will come from the buffer object `myColorData`. The fact that I undid the binding to GL_ARRAY_BUFFER before calling `glDrawArrays` does not change where the data for those attributes comes from.